# Build for IOS with intel XDK not opening another page except first

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, intel-xdk

I am working in App which is using  carodva Media class for recording sound and playing mp3 file from server. For front end, I am using JQuery  mobile framework and also using Ajex call to communicate with server. App has three pages. App is working fine on Android device but when i tried to build setup for ios, it is getting installed properly on device but when i am starting application I am only getting first page. On first page we have buttons which allow to record sound & list file from server are not working. Even , one button simply open new page and there we have few controls is also not working.

Could you please suggest me, do I missing any project setting during build?

I am using latest build of Intel XDK(2366).

I am using following Plugins :-

1. Device
2. Media
3. File
4. Splash Screen

Thanks for your supports.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Please add * in white list intent